# What does the electron g-factor say about charge and mass distribution?

Tags: electrons, quantum-spin

I have researched this question here on Physics.SE to see if it has been answered before.  There are similar questions but none that I can find that answer the specific question I am curious about.

Classical physics suggests that a charged body rotating about its axis of symmetry should have a gyromagnetic ratio shown below if its charge [q] and mass [m] density are distributed identically.
$$
\gamma = \frac{q}{2 m}
$$
The electron g-factor $g_e$ is defined in the following way:
$$
\gamma = \frac{q}{2 m}g_e
$$
Where $q$ is the charge on the electron and $m$ is the mass of the electron.

So, if the g-factor had the value of 1 then from a classical viewpoint, you could say that the mass and charge density were distributed identically.  But, the g-factor for the electron has a measured value a little more than 2.

Question: does this measured value of 2+ say anything about how the charge density and mass density of the electron are distributed differently.  That is, is there a model where an arrangement of mass and charge have been made to yield the measured value of $\approx 2$

Comment: When you say classical do you mean Newtonian or Special Relativity? And I'm not sure what you mean by a distribution of charge or mass for a point particle.

Comment: @qftishard     I think the link does (maybe) answer the question but not in the way I was thinking.  But, it settles it for now.

Comment: @Timaeus  The g-factor for the electron which is considered a non-classical particle is associated with a classical derived gyromagnetic ratio.  So, the very definition seems to span the classical and quantum realm.  I presume that the g-factor can be different from one for reasons other than the classical reasons of the charge and mass distributions being different but I do not know about those other reasons and that was why I asked the question.

Comment: @K7PEH That's 100% completely not an answer to my question. I've seen factors of two differences between taking Relativity into account and not taking relativity into account. And quantum mechanics can obviously make slight corrections to ratios that are otherwise quite close. But I can't tell which factors you are asking about since some people use the word classical to mean not quantum and others use it to mean premodern.

Comment: @Timaeus       OK, I can't answer your question because I was under the impression that the g-factor for the electron was measured, not calculated.  This link, under the section for Gyromagnetic ratio for the electron explains some of the background for my question: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyromagnetic_ratio

Comment: @K7PEH I was just asking you to be precise about the word classical, so we can tell what you mean by it. For instance it is hard to tell you whether you are immediately wrong when you are too vague to be wrong. What do **you** mean when you say classical. Do **you** mean premodern? Do **you** mean non quantum? Or were you just quoting, in which case write the quote, cite it, and thus either way we get the context.

Comment: And if the word classical wasn't relevant then you can omit it. And indeed you make calculations and you make measurements and the goal is for them to match.